# Neo4jRepository @Query result error when there are many relationships for same node

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Let's suppose we use this simple graph model:

```
@NodeEntity
class Ad {    
    // GraphId and more Ad attributes...

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_ADVERTISER", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private User advertiser;

    @Relationship(type = "IS_FAVOURITE_TO", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<User> favourites = new HashSet<>();

    // Getters and setters
 }
```

***EDIT***: Following the advises of one of the aswers, I've tried adding the incoming relationships to User entity, but the problem still remains.

```
@NodeEntity
class User {
    // User attributes. No incoming relationships for HAS_ADVERTISER neither IS_FAVOURITE_TO...

   // EDIT: Added incoming relationships to User entity, but the problem still remains. Tried annotating getters/setters, but neither works
   @Relationship(type = "HAS_ADVERTISER", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
   private Set<Ad> ads = new HashSet<>();

   @Relationship(type = "IS_FAVOURITE_TO", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
   private Set<Ad> favourites = new HashSet<>();

   @Relationship(direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
   public Set<Ad> getAds() {
       return ads;
   }

   @Relationship(direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
   public void setAds(Set<Ad> ads) {
       this.ads = ads;
   }

   @Relationship(direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
   public Set<Ad> getFavourites() {
       return favourites;
   }

   @Relationship(direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
   public void setFavourites(Set<Ad> favourites) {
       this.favourites = favourites;
   }
}
```

If I execute a cypher query to retrieve the ads with advertiser and favourites information through neo4j console, it's simply working well:

```
MATCH (ad:Ad),
(ad)-[has_advertiser:HAS_ADVERTISER]->(advertiser:User),
(ad)-[is_favourite_to: IS_FAVOURITE_TO] -> (favouriteUser:User)
return ad, has_advertiser, advertiser, is_favourite_to, favouriteUser
```

[image]

However, if I execute the query through a `neo4jRepository` instead:

- `advertiser` user is persisted correctly.
- There are two users in `favourites` set: the advertiser user is always added to the set, which is incorrect because there is no `IS_FAVOURITE_TO` relationship with this user.

---

```
@Repository
public interface AdRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Ad> {

    @Query("MATCH (ad:Ad)," +
            "(ad)-[has_advertiser:HAS_ADVERTISER]->(advertiser:User)," +
            "(ad)-[is_favourite_to: IS_FAVOURITE_TO] -> (favouriteUser:User)" +
            "return ad, has_advertiser, advertiser, " +
            "is_favourite_to, favouriteUser ")
    List<Ad> findAds();
 }
```

[image]

Can I change something in my query or my graph model to avoid this? 
Maybe a spring-data-neo4j bug?

Versions:

```
<spring-data-neo4j.version>4.2.0.M1</spring-data-neo4j.version>
<neo4j.ogm.version>2.0.5</neo4j.ogm.version>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the OGM considers this to be an ambiguous model. If you add the incoming relationships to `User`, your issue should be resolved.

**Update**: upon further investigation, this is indeed a bug. Opened https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/276

The workaround is to annotate all your getters and setters (and make sure the @Relationship annotation contains both the relationship type and the direction) in both Ad and User.

Comment: Thanks @Luanne, Didn't know that. So If there is a relationship between two nodes, should I always add the relationship to the two nodes? Is this a general rule? I'll try your suggestion in a few hours and let you know iif the issue is solved. Thanks

Comment: When it's ambiguous like in your case, you have two different relationship types to the same entity, one is a 1:1 and one 1:n. In other cases, you need not map both sides. Let me know though if this fixes it

Comment: Hi @Luanne. I've just tried with your suggestions and I'm afraid the problem still remains...Any idea? Thanks for your time. NOTE that one relationship is 1:1 and  the other one is n:n (not 1:n as you point in your comment). Not sure if it can be related...

Comment: Hmm, when you added the incoming rels, did you annotate both the field and getters/setters with @Relationship specifying INCOMING? (if not, please try that)

Comment: Not sure If I've understood correctly (didn't know that getters/setters can also be annotated with @Relationship). I've tried but neither works (please see my question edit) I've also tired adding the relationship name to the getters/setters, but the same problem. Thanks again

Comment: The relationship type on the annotation is required, but you've already tried that. Possible to send us a test case and/or small data sample to try this out? luanne at graphaware dot com

Comment: Hi again @Luanne. I've sent you a sample project with a test configuration where you can reproduce the error. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

### edited since I missed the cause of the error completely

Spring Data will not populate the embedded Nodes when you return an `Ad` node. You need a dedicated result for this. Also, in your query you return the `has_advertiser` and `is_favourite_to` relations which have no mapping in the `Ad` class. They're completely irrelevant. Change your query to

```
@Query("MATCH (advertiser:User)<-[:HAS_ADVERTISER]-(a:Ad)-[:IS_FAVOURITE_TO]->(favourite:User) 
RETURN a AS ad, advertiser, collect(DISTINCT favourite) AS favourites")
public List<AdWithAdvertiserAndFavouritesResult getAdsWithAdvertisersAndFavourites()
```

The respective result is then

```
@QueryResult
public class AdWithAdvertiserAndFavouritesResult {
    private Ad ad;
    private User advertiser;
    private List<User> favourites;

    //only getters, no setters
}
```

You may want to consider defining an additional property for `Ad` that is unique and can be used as an index later since the query as it is will not scale and induce heavy load: You always match the entire set of `Ad` nodes. I strongly recommend not to do so.

Comment: Hi Cristoph. Thanks for answering but I'm not sure if that's the point. I believe I could get the results here without a `@QueryResult`. See @Luanne answer...Anyway, I still cannot get it working, so I'll give it a try